# Mounting a directory located on an alternate host computer volume. Possible? (Docker)

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker

Problem:  I want to mount a directory to my docker container, but its located on another hard drive.For example:

> /Volumes/alternateDrive/files!

A better explanation below:

Lets take the following scenario:
(I'm using OSX and Boot2Docker)

Say I have a directory of files located at:

> /Volumes/SomeHardDrive/project/ ... files!

I would like to mount this directory in a docker container as follows:

```
docker run -it --name data_volume -v /Volumes/SomeHardDrive/project:/files ubuntu /bin/bash
```

I will then be dropped into a bash shell where i can run the following command:

```
ls -lah /files
```

No joy.

However, this works just dandy:

```
docker run -it --name data_volume -v ~/test_dir_of_files:/files ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Thoughts?

Comment: smells like a permission issue...

Comment: ok, thats great news actually.  I was worried there might be a bug with osx / docker that i didn't know about.

Comment: sorry, i misleaded you. why the second works is because docker mounted the home directory for you. and docker command is against the virtual machine not your osx host. check here for a better understanding of the difference. https://viget.com/extend/how-to-use-docker-on-os-x-the-missing-guide

Comment: oooooh. *lightbulb*  That makes perfect sense.  Thank you!

Comment: You should accept @DynoFu's answer.